# Fail to extract Lat Long from Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I would like to create a list of Lat Long points clicked on a Google Map to insert into a MySQL table. As a start, I tried to display one clicked Lat Long point in a text box. The JavaScript code below is generated from PHP. The map and text box are displayed but not the clicked coordinates. The cursor is a grab hand. A click closes the hand (ready for a drag) and a double click zooms. I am not familiar with JavaScript and have copied the code from others. What have I missed?

```
<style type='text/css'> 
html { height: 100% } 

body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 } 

#map-canvas { height: 80% } 

</style> 

<script type='text/javascript' src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY'> 

</script> 

<script type='text/javascript'> 

function initialize() { var mapOptions = { center: {lat: 55.9355, lng: -4.61192}, 
                                           zoom: 12,
                                           zoomControl: true }; 
                        var map = new google.maps. Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions); }

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
google.maps.event.addListener(map,'click',
   function event() { document.getElementById('latlongclicked').value = event.latLng.lat() + ', ' + event.latLng.lng() })
</script>

<div class='eventtext'> 
  <div>Lat Lng on click: 
  <input type='text' id='latlongclicked'>
  </input>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map,'click', function event() { document.getElementById('latlongclicked').value = event.latLng.lat() + ', ' + event.latLng.lng() })
```

To this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map,'click', function(event) { 
    document.getElementById('latlongclicked').value = event.latLng.lat() + ', ' + event.latLng.lng() 
});
```

You need to refer to `event` as an argument of the function, i.e. `function(event)`... Whereas you're doing `function event ()`

Also you have a problem in that you have `map` defined as a local variable inside your `initialize` function.  But you add the 'click' event listener outside that function, which hasn't got access to it (and will also try doing it before the map has necessarily been created).

Move that event listener inside the initialize function too (or make it a global variable, i.e. define `var map;` at the top of your javascript)

e.g. this should work

```
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: {
            lat: 55.9355,
            lng: -4.61192
        },
        zoom: 12,
        zoomControl: true
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
    document.getElementById('latlongclicked').value = event.latLng.lat() + ', ' + event.latLng.lng()
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Thanks, Duncan. Unfortunately, with the change the results were the same. However, on reading addListener docs, it seems that the first parameter 'map' should be omitted. This also made no difference. I guess I need to read up on JavaScript.

Comment: You only omit the 'map' parameter, if you're using the shorthand version where the addListener event is called directly on the map object itself, e.g. `map.addListener('click', function() {...});`

Comment: Just saw another problem with your code; I've updated my answer to cover that too.

Comment: Duncan, Thanks so much for your help. I was getting nowhere with it and had spent a few hours in vain. Now to get multiple points!